# Modify text file with php code

Tags: php, json, self-modifying

I have a JSON file badly formatted (doc1.json):

```
{"text":"xxx","user":{"id":96525997,"name":"ss"},"id":29005752194568192}
{"text":"yyy","user":{"id":32544632,"name":"cc"},"id":29005753951977472}
{...}{...}
```

And I have to change it in this:

```
{"u":[
{"text":"xxx","user":{"id":96525997,"name":"ss"},"id":29005752194568192},
{"text":"yyy","user":{"id":32544632,"name":"cc"},"id":29005753951977472},
{...},{...}
]}
```

Can I do this in a PHP file?

Comment: The json you want to modify is not a valid json string. `[{"test":"test":},{"test2":"test2"}]` would be valid

Comment: @ treegarden : just one ' : ' is extra after {"test":"test":}

Comment: oops, yes you are right. I can't edit the comment anymore though.

Comment: I don't care about what the file has ,,, you just need to add  {"u":[  in the beginning  and ]} at the end ..... right ??

Comment: @MohammadAlabed : he also needs to add ',' between each json/line

Answer (score 1):

```
//Get the contents of file
    $fileStr = file_get_contents(filelocation);

//Make proper json
    $fileStr = str_replace('}{', '},{', $fileStr);

//Create new json    
    $fileStr = '{"u":[' . $fileStr . ']}';

//Insert the new string into the file
    file_put_contents(filelocation, $fileStr);
```

Comment: You might need to account for EOL characters as well. OP is unclear as to whether each JSON object in original file is on separate line

Comment: your answer works, to print the result .. but not directly editing the text file that I query!

Comment: @K0pp0 : I have edited the answer.Now it will edit the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I would build the data structure you want from the file:

```
$file_path = '/path/to/file';
$array_from_file = file($file_path);

// set up object container
$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->u = array();

// iterate through lines from file
// load data into object container
foreach($array_from_file as $json) {
    $line_obj = json_decode($json);
    if(is_null($line_obj)) {
        throw new Exception('We have some bad JSON here.');
    } else {
        $obj->u[] = $line_obj;
    }
}

// encode to JSON
$json = json_encode($obj);

// overwrite existing file
// use 'w' mode to truncate file and open for writing
$fh = fopen($file_path, 'w');
// write JSON to file
$bytes_written = fwrite($fh, $json);
fclose($fh);
```

This assumes each of the JSON object repsentations in your original file are on a separate line.

I prefer this approach over string manipulation, as you can then have built in checks where you are decoding JSON to see if the input is valid JSON format that can be de-serialized.  If the script operates successfully, this guarantees that your output will be able to be de-serialized by the caller to the script.

Comment: your answer works, to print the result .. but not directly editing the text file that I query!

Comment: @K0pp0 You never mentioned the need to edit the source text file in question.  If that is what you want to do, rather than echo out the result, you just write it to the file (overwriting the existing content).  I have updated answer to show this operation.